# How to stop multiple iDevices from sharing iCloud-sync'ed information?

Tags: ios, apple-id

Wife just got a iPad mini, we already have an iPad and an iPhone. Now all 3 are linked together -- they share Contacts, Notes, Reminders, etc.  We want to unlink all of them.

I know there has got to be an easy way but just can't figure it out.

Do we need all different AppleIDs or different accounts? And if so how we do that and then assign/change the different devices to the different IDs?

Comment: What do you mean by "linked" (what is the effect you are seeing but rather don't want to have)?

Comment: By linked I mean all 3 now have the same contact list. With the new mini, when we were finished setting it up it had the same one as on the iPad and iPhone. That when I delete something from one of them it deletes it on all. Like a favorite in safari.

Comment: So when you set up these 3 devices you used the same Apple ID

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to accommodate lush you goal is by doing the following:

1. Delete account from Settings > iCloud
2. When asked to keep on iPad or delete, choose whether you would like that same information saved but be able to edit it without it affecting other device's information.
3. Choose set up a free Apple ID and proceed through the setup

The pros of this scenario:

1. Having the other devices using the new Apple ID to receive their own free 5 GB of iCloud storage
2. You will still be able to use the other Apple ID for iTunes and App Stores
3. Edit the content from the old iCloud account without those iCloud devices being affected from the changes
4. Utilize the iPhone cellular calls with iPad and other features of iCloud which are functionally made to be segregated between people

The cons:

1. Another email / password combination to remember.

Other information:

1. You can still share photos between accounts using iCloud photo sharing
2. Check the Apple ID used in Settings > Messages and Settings > FaceTime to ensure the proper Apple ID is being used, otherwise all devices could be sharing text messages and phone calls.
3. Additionally, you can setup Family Sharing in order to keep using apps, music and other media already payed for, and paying for future purchases with the same credit card.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > iCloud

If you want to completely unlink them, and create a new iCloud account for each, scroll to the bottom and choose Delete Account - be **very** sure that this is what you want to do though!

If you just want to stop syncing between devices, just change the sliders on the page and turn off the things you don't want synced.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stop something like contacts or safari etc, just go to:

Settings --> iCloud

And you can pick anything to turn off. This means, you don't have to create multiple accounts. You may have to do this on both devices, but this does work. Hope this helps! Also the options are fairly limited, so some of the features you are looking for may not be there.